# Accessing local host / reading php files - WINDOWS MAMP

Tags: php, windows, mamp

So I am very new to this all but I want to learn.
I have downloaded MAMP for windows, and ran it. It greenlights mysql and apache.
I thought at this point I would have able to open .php files locally and get a desired display but instead it still shows up as hard code.
Am I skipping steps?

Comment: `MAMP` for MS-Windows? Has the world gone totally nuts? EDIT: ok, seems this really exists. _Why? Just why?_.

Comment: Lol I was waiting for that response. So anyway yes. It exists and I have it. Should I just... you know... not have it. and have something else? Or try to get this to work anyway.

Comment: I am afraid with that little information you gave no one will be able to help. You ask: "Am I skipping steps?"... But you do not say at all what steps you performed...

Comment: My suggestion: 1. look into your apache http servers error log file (which you have to monitor constantly anyway when implementing php in a web environment) and 2. check your apache http servers php configuration.

Comment: running as `http://localhost` or as `file:///`? big difference here @Wynx `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- As always: a very good idea ;-) Though the term "running" cringles my toe nails...

Comment: Lol unfortunately I did list all my steps.

Comment: @arkascha having a green light everywhere is fine but we don't know what they're doing as I pointed out in my earlier comment.

Comment: I was trying to view my pages as file://

Comment: @Fred-ii- Absolutely correct. Though I still wonder why green lights are so important when operating server side logic... Maybe just to make people think they are the ones with the green light sabers...

Comment: In my mamp preferences, on the web server tab, it says document root: C:\MAMP\htdocs.

Comment: @Wynx that's what I thought and I closed the question with a duplicate for it.

Comment: @arkascha ^ wink

Comment: @arkascha yeah I know. colors can be deceiving ;-) it's how we perceive that sets them apart.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Except in case of color blindness...

Comment: @arkascha which is what I meant; you read between those lines quite well ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hm, sorry, Sir, you apparently confuse me with someone else. I do not know how to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your php project's folder or simple php files inside

> C:\mamp\htdocs\your_project_folder

or single file program

> C:\mamp\htdocs\simple_program.php

and start the Apache Server using MAMP Control Panel

In Browser visit:

**For Full Project**

> `localhost/your_project_folder/index[.php, .html]`

or for simple single file php programs located at `htdocs\your_program.php`

> `localhost/your_program.php`

You can put PHP or HTML files inside `htdocs` folder ans then you can access them by localhost.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad It was useful.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to several reasons, you should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/7838027

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been a comment.

Comment: or flagged as a duplicate

Comment: @arkascha I can't put comments to question for some reason, maybe because I am a new member :/